# What is the meaning of the phrase "an algebraic increase"?

Tags: optimization, definition

In a [paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10107-012-0514-2.pdf) on optimization methods I find the following excerpt:

> "Often, a “strong” version of the Wolfe condition is imposed,
> insisting on a reduction in the absolute value of the directional
> derivative, in contrast to the standard condition that requires only
> an algebraic increase. The latter is all that is required to ensure
> positive definiteness of the updated inverse Hessian approximation."

What does the phrase *algebraic increase* mean here?

Answer (score 1):

I believe they just mean "without absolute value". More precisely, they mean whatever the two versions of the condition say. What can happen in the weak version is that the directional derivate goes from slightly negative to large and positive – thereby overshooting the mark. In the strong version, this is controlled.